# Soap Request/Response without WSDL

Tags: .net, vb.net, soap

I have to query once an hour to a remote web server to recieve data.  However the remote web site does not use web services and state in thier 300+ page document that:

Although SOAP is a recognized Web Services API, the RTO web server does not offer a web services
interface. That is, there is no Web Services Description Language (WSDL) file available for usage by
participant web services client software.

So my question is how do send a soap request and get a response without the use of a WSDL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Build the XML yourself, using your choice of XML API (XmlDocument, LINQ to XML)
2. Send the message using WebRequest

Comment: I have written the soap envelope along with the soap queries and tried sending them via Httpwebrequest to the secure web site. I know i'm getting past the credential part of it and I believe i'm getting it to post the xml to get the xml query however i'm not getting anything back from the remote web server, prior to asking this question.  All the examples i've seen on the web have stated that you have to have a wsdl (web service), and as i've stated that isn't an option for me.  

i've searched for about 2 weeks on google trying to find the answer and have had no luck.